# Why SVM gridsearch takes longer time?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, predictive-modeling, feature-selection, hyperparameter

I have a dataset of 5K records and 60 features focussed on binary classification. Please find my code below for SVM paramter tuning. It's running for a longer time than `Xgb`.`LR` and `Rf`. The other algorithms mentioned returned results within minutes (10-15 mins) whereas SVM is running for more than 45 mins.

**Questions**

1) Is SVM usually slower and takes longer time?

2) Is there any issue with my code below?

3) How can I make the gridsearch faster?

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
param_grid = {'C': [0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000],  
              'gamma': [1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001], 
              'kernel': ['linear', 'rbf','poly'],
              'class_weight':['balanced']}
svm=SVC()
svm_cv=GridSearchCV(svm,param_grid,cv=5)
svm_cv.fit(X_train_std,y_train)
```

Comment: There are completely different algorithms and completely different numbers of runs, it is hard to compare them. Additionally, some algorithms run using all cores by default, and `SVM` probably not. Try using `n_jobs=-1` in `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: Hi, Is there any stacking tutorial that you know of which can help a beginner like me? I am searching online but couldn't find anything which kind of easy to understand for a noob

Comment: Stacking makes sens when you are at the stage, when every hyperparameter you could optimize is optimized already, and stacking is the only way to improve the model more. Reading your questions I realize you are at the stage of seaching a starting point to begin optimization. Additionally, your dataset is rather too small for advanced stacking, you should rather think about simple blending of the results of **optimized** models.

Comment: SVM is rather expensive to train. XGBClassier is working faster, because default number of trees is just 100. If you want to achieve better scores, I'd rather expect gradient boosting to perform better than SVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, optimization problem of SVM is of quadratic order. 
Just check first line of [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)

> "The fit time scales at least quadratically with the number of samples and may be impractical beyond tens of thousands of samples."

Answer (score 1):

1) I will cite Noah Weber's answer

> The fit time scales at least quadratically with the number of samples and may be impractical beyond tens of thousands of samples.

2) There is nothing wrong but you are entirely searching a space that is

> 7 * 5 * 3 * 1 * 5(fold) = 525

which is pretty big.

3) To boost your training you can do the training in a subsample or just reducing the search space, I normally use the following function:

```py
def fit_cv_subsample (pipe_cv, X, y, n_max = 10_000):
    '''
    This function fits a CV in a subsample of the first n_max rows
    returns the trained pipe and the best estimator
    '''
    X_sub = X[0:n_max]
    y_sub = y[0:n_max]
    pipe_cv.fit(X_sub,y_sub)
    #pipe_cv.best_estimator_.fit(X,y)
    return pipe_cv, pipe_cv.best_estimator_
results, best_model = fit_cv_subsample(svm_c, X, y)
```